# Difference between message types in IDOC's SAP ABAP

Tags: idoc

Can someone tell me the difference between IDOC message type CREMAS and CREFET I have tried searching for this on few web sites but they are not clear.

Thank you

Comment: did you already try to use the f1 help?

Comment: No I haven't tried it,
Thanks for that

Comment: So what's your use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BD87 - from the "Message Type" field (F4):

```
CREFET  Get vendor data
CREMAS  Vendor master data distribution
```

And I fear it's all I could find. I guess you can find more just by reading the documentation about how to configure iDocs (assign segments, function modules and so).

Maybe you can tell us what is not clear in what you've found in those few sites... it's more probably someone around here can give you further help if you do it.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with this answer. I fear the answer the OP needs is the one to a generic question like "what's the difference of any two message types?" or "what are iDoc message types for?".